# How to include user's email in SalesForce email response?

Tags: email, templates, salesforce

I have an email-to-case setup in SalesForce.

When one of my coworkers responds to the case with an email to the user, how can I setup SalesForce to automatically include the original email in the response email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin Setup ->Communication Template -> Email Template

Selevt Field Type -> Email Message Field ->
field -> text field.

Here is your merge field.

{!EmailMessage.TextBody}

This work for you?